# Tensorflow: Saving subset of variables from previously created model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I have created a model (Model A) with a bunch of variables. I plan to do transfer learning with Model A on a new model (Model B) using some of the layers from Model A. However, Model B has the same architecture as Model A so I can't just load all variables from model A before running Model B or else there will be errors with naming, etc. So, I am trying to create a new ckpt file that only stores the weights that I want from Model A. I will then use this new ckpt file to load into Model B. I have the following:

```
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('ModelA.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(sess, 'ModelA.ckpt')

# I did not explicity name my variables in model A so I am just placing them in the list and taking the ones I want

store_list = []
for v in tf.trainable_variables():
    store_list.append(v)

var_list={"W_1": store_list[0], "b_1": store_list[1]}
v2_saver=tf.train.Saver(var_list)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
v2_saver.save(sess, 'model_A_subset.ckpt')
```

However when I restore model_A_subset.ckpt I still have all the variables from ModelA.ckpt. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way I can easily delete the variables I don't want from ModelA.ckpt and use that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the unnecessary variables are in the checkpoint? I ask because before restoring a checkpoint you need to create the graph, and if you're creating a graph with all variables of A in it you'll have this problem.

To inspect the checkpoint and see what's actually there try the [inspect checkpoint tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py).

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding inspect_checkpoint but when I reload the subset model in a new script I am simply doing `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('Model_A_subset.ckpt.meta')` which should create my graph and then `saver.restore(sess, 'Model_A_subset.ckpt')` so how would the graph even have knowledge of the unnecessary variables if they were never written to it?

Comment: Ah, when you reload the metagraph it comes with the entire graph of the other model, not just its variables.